# How to convert NameValueCollection to Hashtable

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I have a `NameValueCollection` object and I need to convert it to a `Hashtable` object, preferrably in one line of code. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should consider using a generic [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) instead since it's strongly-typed, whereas a [`Hashtable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) isn't. Try this:

```
NameValueCollection col = new NameValueCollection();
col.Add("red", "rouge");
col.Add("green", "verde");
col.Add("blue", "azul");

var dict = col.AllKeys
              .ToDictionary(k => k, k => col[k]);
```

**EDIT:** Based on your comment, to get a HashTable you could still use the above approach and add one more line. You could always make this work in one line but 2 lines are more readable.

```
Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable(dict);
```

Alternately, the pre-.NET 3.5 approach using a loop would be:

```
Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable();
foreach (string key in col)
{
    hashTable.Add(key, col[key]);
}
```

Comment: the problem is that I'm using an API that expects a `Hashtable` so using a `Dictionary` is not an option...

Comment: there is a catch here. NameValueCollection allows duplicate keys. In that case, all values are inserted for the same key in HashTable. there is only one entry per unique key. e.g. if you have "red" key listed twice against "rouge" and "verde" values, both values will be listed against hash key "red" as a single key.

Comment: @Priyank good point! Some post processing would need to be done to apply any special handling depending on the OP's needs.

Answer (score 2):

It takes more than one line but it's decently simple

```
NameValueCollection nv = new NameValueCollection();
Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable();

nv.Add("test", "test");

foreach (string key in nv.Keys)
{
    hashTable.Add(key, nv[key]);
}
```

It compiles and executes as expected.